# CSS Font "Helvetica Neue"

Tags: css, fonts

I often see the websites using font "Helvetica Neue". Is this font safe to use, like eg. Arial? Or do the browsers have trouble rendering it or not many machines have this font? Thanks.

Comment: Note, iOS 7 and OS X 10.9 now include Light and Ultra Thin in 'Helvetica Neue', whereas the "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light" on previous version lack these weights.

Comment: Humm, i wonder : Who else did cut the use of this font?

Comment: I wonder why it is `neue` and not `new` for helvetica.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This font is not standard on all devices. It is installed by default on some Macs, but rarely on PCs and mobile devices.

To use this font on all devices, use a [@font-face declaration](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) in your CSS to link to it on your domain if you wish to use it.

```
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; font-weight: bold; src: url('Delicious-Bold.otf'); }
```

Taken from [css3.info](http://www.css3.info)

Comment: Just mind the copyright if you do. Make sure the licence you pay for includes web embedding.

Answer (score 83):

It's a default font on Macs, but rare on PCs.  Since it's not technically web-safe, some people may have it and some people may not.  If you want to use a font like that, without using @font-face, you may want to write it out several different ways because it might not work the same for everyone.

I like using a font stack that touches on all bases like this:

```
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", 
  Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
```

This recommended font-family stack is further described in this CSS-Tricks snippet [Better Helvetica](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/better-helvetica/) which uses a `font-weight: 300;` as well.

Answer (score 19):

Helvetica Neue is a paid font, so you shouldn't @font-face it, as you'd be freely distributing a copyrighted font. It's included in Mac systems but not in windows/linux ones, so yes, plenty of your users wont have it installed. Anyway, you can use 'Arial Narrow' as a windows substitute, which is it's windows equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to encode any font for websites. It'll generate the code to include the font.

I don't really use it for fonts over 30px. They look much better as an image (because images are anti-aliased, and some browsers don't anti-alias fonts in the browser).

See: http://www.truetype-typography.com/ttalias.htm

Hope that helps...

Comment: It should be mentioned that you can only use the font-face generator if you have the legal right (license) to use a font on a website through font-face.  Helvetica is a paid font, so you'd need to purchase a license to use it.

Comment: You bet. Fontsquirrel will actually block you from processing Helvetica. See https://typekit.com/lists/alternatives-to-helvetica for other options.

Comment: Using images is not not the only option anymore: http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Comment: This answer didn't age well. Anti-aliasing is supported now by most of the browsers. https://devhints.io/css-antialias

Answer (score 1):

Most windows users won't have that font on their computers. Also, you can't just submit it to your server and call it using font-face because this isn't a free font...

And last, but not least, answering the question that nobody mentioned yet, Helvetica and Helvetica Neue do not render well on screen unless they have a really big `font-size`. You'll find a lot of pages using this font, and in all of them you'll see that the top border of a line of text looks wavy and that some letters look taller than others. In my opinion this is the main reason why you shouldn't use it. There are other options for you to use, like Open Sans.